# Rails: sending ajax object using Jquery and keeping datatype on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using Jquery for creating object and sending to server:

```
    data = {};
    data.number = 5;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some_link',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function() {
            alert('data sent');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
```

And on rails, I test submitted param by:

```
params[:number] => "5"
```

How can I force rails to understand 5 instead of "5". Because I send a large bunch of data, I cannot manually do conversion.

Thanks

Comment: Sending JSON over an API will always convert your arguments into strings no matter what. What do you plan on doing with the data after your api receives it?

Comment: I received those data save to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to save to a database, then your model should have the attribute type set as `integer`. When you save it, it will automatically coerce the string `'5'` into the integer `5`